# Can't start TeamCity and Build agent

Tags: linux, tomcat, teamcity

My TeamCity suddenly stopped working. It fails to execute runAll.sh start/stop. Reboot the machine and kill by PID don't  help either.

CentOS7, TeamCity 2018.2

Output from the command line:

```
[root@host bin]# ./runAll.sh stop
Java executable is found: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java'
Using CATALINA_BASE: /opt/TeamCity
Using CATALINA_HOME: /opt/TeamCity
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/TeamCity/temp
Using JRE_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6.x86_64/jre
Using CLASSPATH: /opt/TeamCity/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/TeamCity/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID: /opt/TeamCity/bin/../logs/teamcity.pid
PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted.
Stopping TeamCity build agent...
Java executable is found: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java'
Starting TeamCity Build Agent Launcher...
Agent home directory is /opt/TeamCity/buildAgent
Received stop command from console.
Sending agent shutdown command to: http://localhost:9090
Failed to shutdown agent gracefully: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
Cannot stop agent gracefully, you can try to kill agent by './agent.sh stop kill' command
```

Output from Catalina's log:

```
25-Dec-2018 20:35:48.289 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8105]: 
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:769)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:715)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
```

<..>

```
25-Dec-2018 20:35:48.563 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Change Observer 1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What can be a reason or a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The follow steps have helped me to resolve this issue:

1. runAll.sh stop force (2 times) - kill all running teamcity's activities (additionally - agent.sh stop kill)
2. adjust service's settings:

   ```
   server:
   Type=forking
   PIDFile=/opt/TeamCity/logs/teamcity.pid
   ```

   &

   ```
   agent:
   Type=oneshot
   RemainAfterExit=yes
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From [java.net.BindException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/BindException.html) documentation:

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to bind a socket to a local address and port.
>   Typically, the port is in use, or the requested local address could not be assigned.

so, or port is in use or you don't have permission to open port...

i guess you have troubles because of firewall on centos

Comment: I've stopped firewall ports and now teamcity can start. But some time ago teamcity was running with active firewall too. **firewall-cmd --permanent --list-all** says me both ports for server and for agent are open.